# Objective-C : Accessing fields in implementation

Tags: objective-c, field, getter

Is it possible to fields defined **only** in implementation but not in interface definition ?

```
@interface MyInterface .... @end --> dict not defined here!!!

@implementation MyInterface 
...
NSDictionary *dict;
...
@end
```

In this case if somewhere I somehow accessed to this class, can I access to the `dict` or should I create a `getter` just like in Java ?

---

Edit after @Rob's answer

Thanks for the answer Rob, I wish I have the implementation of these interface and classes. Instead I am trying to bind two different libraries ( I know it is reallllly bad as architectural point of view but this is where I end up).

Basically, I am in react-native world. And we are using react-native-video as our player layer. But since AVPlayer does not support some subtitle types our head company sent us a library that needs a player instance and a view instance to draw subtitle on the view. I believe they will bind to events of the player and draw sub titles based on player states.

So react-native-video is in this [github](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video) repo with the [interface](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/ios/Video/RCTVideo.h) and [implementation](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/ios/Video/RCTVideo.m).

I find the UIView that includes the properties and casted it to the object itself RTCVideo in this case). But now I am stuck. I can go and change some stuff as per your suggestion in the "Development Pods" to be able to access but this is my last bullet :) I prefer to convince these two libraries in a friendly way :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the above syntax isn't what you want. The modern way to do this is with a class extension.

Your header file is the same:

```
@interface MyInterface
@end
```

But in your `.m` file, you create an extension by appending `()`:

```
@interface MyInterface ()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSDictionary *dict;
@end
```

Now, inside your `.m` file, you can access `self.dict` normally, but outside of your `.m` file it won't appear available.

For full details, see Programming with Objective-C: [Class Extensions Extend the Internal Implementation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3).

The syntax you've written actually creates a static (global) variable called `dict` that isn't tied to any instance.

It is possible to create raw instance variables using a `{...}` syntax, either on the extension or on the implementation, but this isn't used that often today, except for managing raw buffers that you don't want accessors for. The syntax is either:

```
@interface MyInterface () {
    NSDictionary *_dict;
}

...
@end
```

or on the implementation:

```
@implementation MyInterface {
    NSDictionary *_dict;
}

...
@end
```

But I recommend simple extensions with properties any time you can. And if you are considering creating an accessor for it, you definitely want to use `@property` and let the system do it for you.

---

If I understand your edits correctly, you're trying to read the internal ivars of an object that doesn't expose them with an accessor, correct? I believe specifically you want to access [`_player`](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/ios/Video/RCTVideo.m#L27).

There's several common ways to do that. The key feature you want is [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html).

The simplest approach for this problem is `-valueForKey:`

```
AVPlayer *player = [view valueForKey:@"player"];
```

The first thing `-valueForKey:` looks for is `_<key>`, and if it's just an object pointer (as in this case), it just returns it.

(This can be broken if a class return `false` for `+accessInstanceVariablesDirectly`, but the default is `true`, and it's unusual to override this.)

Another very common approach is to just declare any methods you know exist as a category. (This won't work for `_player`, since it's not a method, but in case you need similar things.) Imagine you wanted to call the "private" method `-removePlayerTimeObserver`. In your `.m` file, just say you know about it using a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW2):

```
@interface RCTVideo (PrivateMethods)
- (void)removePlayerTimeObserver;
@end
```

And since you know about it, you can call it:

```
[video removePlayerTimeObserver];
```

If you're wrong, and that method doesn't really exist, then the program will crash. In Objective-C, almost all rules are advisory. You can break them if you want to. ObjC programmers tend to be big rule-followers because otherwise the program crashes and ObjC has very clear rules that are pretty easy to follow. It's not because the system forces us to.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I edited the question as per your answer. Basically I am trying to hach(ish) into the the target implementation. Would appreciate if you can have a look at the edit.

Comment: but wait what he wrote should still have worked, unless no (){} was the problem?

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik I'm not sure what you mean. (Are you responding to my original misunderstanding of his question, about how to create per-instance ivars, or his actual question, about how to read other object's ivars?) His original syntax creates a static variable, not an ivar.

Comment: oh i read his code too fast, i thought he put it interface nm

Comment: Thanks a lot, obv I am soo junior to obj-c :) but quite fast at learning. Will comeback after trying these. Glad for your time :)